# Definition of weil restriction via descent data

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand Galois descent and Weil restriction.  From these notes:

[image]

I understand that the product in the definition of $\tilde{X}$ is a product of $K'$-schemes, and that $\tilde{X}$ is an $F$-scheme via the projection onto the factor corresponding to the inclusion map $K' \subseteq F$ (so, an initial choice of embedding $K' \rightarrow F$):

$$\tilde{X} \rightarrow X' \times_{K'} F \rightarrow \textrm{Spec}(F)$$

What is $\sigma^{\ast}\tilde{X}$ supposed to be?  What does this have to do with an isomorphism $\varphi_{\sigma}: \sigma^{\ast} \tilde{X} \rightarrow \tilde{X}$, and what does this have to do with $G$ permuting the embeddings of $K'$ into $F$?

Comment: If $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(F/K)$ and $\iota : K' \to F$ is an embedding of $K$-algebra then $\sigma \circ \iota$ is an embedding $K' \to F$ of $K$-algebra.

Comment: The scheme $\sigma^*\tilde{X}$ is $\tilde{X}\times_{F,\sigma} F$ where $F$ is seen as a $F$-algebra via $\sigma$. The map $\varphi_\sigma$ is just the projection onto the first factor, which is a $K$-isomorphism (but this is not a $F$-morphism). Modulo the decomposition of $\tilde{X}$ into factors of the form $X'\times_{K',i} F$, the maps $\varphi_\sigma$ permutes the factors.